# Should drives be unmounted before cloning with Rufus?

Tags: disk-image, rufus

In a Unix-based environment, when cloning a disk to an image file with `dd`, the disk should be unmounted to prevent errors due to the filesystem changing during the cloning process. When using Rufus on Windows 10 and above to accomplish an analogous task (saving a disk to a  VHD image file), is it best practice to have the source disk unmounted or at least mounted as a read-only drive?

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/34) that support for mounted volumes preceded support for unmounted ones in Rufus, which would suggest that using an unmounted volume as the source was not the originally intended use case. Is there reason why unmounting is expected for `dd` but not Rufus?

Comment: For non-thumb-drive (SCSI RMB = 0) you can try to set the disk to offline (in Disk Management). Either way I don't think it matters much in Windows. AFAIK it doesn't work quite like Linux as in you won't get some residual mount record or so which could makes things ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rufus dev here.

On Windows "unmounting" is actually equivalent to requesting exclusive access (which, if successful, means that only the application that requested access can read or write the drive, and that any other application will be prevented from accessing it at the same time), **which Rufus performs automatically**.

So you don't have to take any specific steps with regards to your disk before using Rufus.

Windows does have a "dismount" capability, but the twist is, you cannot actually format or write to a volume when it is dismounted, since, again, it is different from the UNIX unmount that only removes a mounted volume from an existing file system.

For more on this, and for the steps that Rufus does follow to format a drive, see [this official documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_dismount_volume) and especially the *To change a volume file system* section that lists the following actions:

1. Open a volume.
2. Lock the volume.
   *NB: This is the part where we get exclusive access, and where no other application will be able to access the volume.*
3. Format the volume.
4. Dismount the volume.
5. Unlock the volume.
6. Close the volume handle.

Obviously, this is what Rufus follows as well. And as you can see, in the Windows world, "dismounting" the volume needs to occur **after** formatting it, not before.

Oh and for the record, Rufus can also write drives in DD mode (i.e. similar to using the UNIX `dd` command), in which case no formatting needs to occur, but where we also do request an exclusive lock to the drive to ensure that no other application can interfere with the data that is being written by Rufus.

Now, of course, once Rufus is done writing or formatting the drive, it does relinquish the exclusive lock and closes the disk or volume handle it held, which means that third party application may still attempt to alter data (and as a matter of fact, if the new volume contains a file system that Windows can mount, Windows will automatically create a hidden `System Volume Information` folder with a bunch of files there), so we have no way of guaranteeing that the drive or volume will not be modified once we are done copying the data. But we can however guarantee that, if we obtained the lock, the data that was written by the time we relinquished the lock, will not have been interfered with, as the OS is meant to enforce that an application that has a lock to a drive or volume is the only application that can access that device.

**EDIT:** I am now realizing that your question related to saving to VHD, so, so I'm just going to point out that, there again, we do request a lock to the drive in order to obtain exclusive access.
Especially [this part of the code](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/e86523e024278aefa43631d74729268ca0a8e108/src/format.c#L1994-L1996) relating to saving to VHD indicates that we call `GetPhysicalHandle()` with the second parameter set to `TRUE` and if you are to look at the [definition of `GetPhysicalHandle()`](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/e86523e024278aefa43631d74729268ca0a8e108/src/drive.c#L234-L244) you will find out that the second parameter is set to `TRUE` when requesting a lock. Still to be safe, and especially because Windows juggles both volumes and drives, if you are worried that a third party application may be trying to write data to the drive while you are cloning it, you may try to temporarily remove the drive letter in disk manager and restore it when you are done.

Comment: Thank you for chiming in here.  The question was talking about the source disk. Your answer appears to refer to the target disk.

Comment: I am talking about the source disk (at least for the EDIT, that was added before your comment). I kept the other part because it is related to how one achieves the same as unmounting in Windows and may interest people.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't get more authoritative than an answer from you. It's a relief to know that the user does not need to handle this behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a long time sine I used it but I dont think that Rufus works analagously to dd - specifically dd does a bit copy, while Rufus formats the target, copies the required files and adds a boot loader or similar.

Thus while ideally dd wants thecdisk unmounted (but at least not changing during the copy - which could cause the file table to be different to the final location of files - if they have been modified or deleted during the copy) Rufus works on a fole-by-file basis so tjis restriction is irrelevant.

I **assume** that at some point RUFUS learnt how to mount iso and other block devices so it could grab the files off them.

Comment: Ah, it seems you are right when it comes to the default ISO mode, although it can also dispatch to DD mode, which copies byte by byte kind of like `dd`.